# apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome error

Tags: system-installation

When I try to install vpn I get this:

```
root@root:~# apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package network-manager-openvpn-gnome is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'network-manager-openvpn-gnome' has no installation candidate
root@root:~#
```

Comment: Is your problem get solved?

Answer (score 1):

The package `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` is in **Universe** repository of Ubuntu.

Enable this repository first.

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Then install using

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Extra suggestion, don't be root. Use `sudo` whenever possible.